# How to stop div from moving up when using mousemove?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to keep the box from being dragged up, but can be dragged down, this is what I came up with but I can't figure out how to keep the original position so I have a reference to add it to the if check. It only appears after you scroll the main body a bit.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/29r6mnov/1/)

```
window.addEventListener("scroll",function(){
  if($(document).scrollTop() > 100){
    $( ".box" ).slideDown({
      start: function () {
        $(this).css({
          display: "flex"
        })
      }
    });    
  }

  var top = 0;
  var divOverlay = document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0];
  var is_clicked = false;

  divOverlay.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){   
    is_clicked = true;
    top = divOverlay.offsetTop - e.clientY
  }, true);

  document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(){
    is_clicked = false;
  }, true);

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){  
    event.preventDefault();

    // add a check here so it doesn't allow dragging the container up?
    if(is_clicked){
      divOverlay.style.top  = (e.clientY + top) + 'px';

      // if the box reaches 50px down, it should automatically hide it if the user
      //$('.box').slideUp();
    }
  }, true);

})
```

Comment: can you please describe the desired behavior a bit more explicit? It's not easy to understand what you pretend.

Comment: @Vickel After you scroll down a bit on the example, and the blue box slides up, there's a down arrow, once you click on the arrow, I want to be able to drag the whole div down (as it's currently doing), or back up to the same exact position but it shouldn't allow to go higher than the original position. Pretty much a checker, to see if it's back to the original position in case I slide up again, or if I slide it down, I'm going to hide the box once it reaches the bottom.

Comment: maybe your fiddle's version posted here is not correct, I cannot see any blue box, can you double-check?

Comment: @Vickel I updated it here http://jsfiddle.net/29r6mnov/1/

Comment: and with "drag" you want to drag (jQuery draggable) or get it to a new position programmatically?

Comment: think it'd be easier with position, não achas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `Math.max` to limit the maximum top position of the box to viewport height minus box height:

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
  event.preventDefault();

  // add a check here so it doesn't allow dragging the container up?
  var maxTop = window.innerHeight - divOverlay.offsetHeight;
  if(is_clicked){
    divOverlay.style.top  = Math.max(maxTop, e.clientY + top) + 'px';

    // if the box reaches 50px down, it should automatically hide it if the user
    //$('.box').slideUp();
  }
}, true);
```